# Wordpress: Nested Loop: Loop 6 posts, Loop same w/ different code, Repeat

Tags: loops, wordpress-theming, nested-loops, wordpress

I'm trying to get a nested loop working that will display 6 posts with a certain code, then go back, display the same 6 posts with a different code and then continue doing this until there are no more posts.

Example:

```
A B C D E F   
a b c d e f  
G H I J K L   
g h i j k l
```

So far I've managed to find this code:
http://pastebin.com/hBkYvy6U
but it only repeats the loop on the first 6 posts and, afterwards, it simply outputs the posts once.

Probably the second output isn't nested correctly into the first one, can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing line 27 to use modulo % operator or fmod function instead of if($count == 6 )

That should give your the expected result for all items in the list by repeating this action for every post  6 at a time (6,12,18,24,...).

```
if($count % 6 ==0  && $count !=0) // should give you what you are looking for


example of modulo and fmod use

<?php
$var1 = 5;
$var2 = 2;

echo $var1 % $var2; //Returns 1
echo fmod($var1,$var2); //Also returns the same
?>
```

Comment: Hi Dany, thanks for helping me out. With the code you posted now I'm getting the output of the second loop on every post of the first on instead of every 6 posts, do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you needed. Just to make sure : Do you need to : query all elements lets say 24 elements, every time i display 6 item run a second query with these 6 elements, repeat with another block of 6 element ?

Comment: I have corrected my example which was missing an important test against 0. LEt me know if that does the trick

Comment: Thank you! It posts accordingly on every sixth post now, the problem now is that the second loop is not duplicating the previous six posts, instead it just posts the same content over and over.

Comment: After much trial and error I finally managed to get it to work by defining a variable for the offset and increasing it's number with every post outputted! Thanks for your help!

Comment: (I'll leave the link for the final result in case anyone else wants to do this http://pastebin.com/guccGZE9)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to reset your count = 0 after you find that count = 6

ie:

```
// If count is equal to 6
            if( $count == 6 ) : 
                               //reset my counter
                               count = 0;

                // Second query
                $my_second_query = new WP_Query;
                $my_second_query->query( array( 'posts_per_page' => '6' ) );
```

Comment: Hi Brian, I tried adding the count reset in the meantime but it still isn't working.